# Cats MonadError with Try doesn't complie

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, monads, scala-cats

I just found a MonadError code snippet that uses `Either` like the following

```scala
  import cats.MonadError
  import cats.instances.either._ // for MonadError

  type ErrorOr[A] = Either[String, A]
  val monadError = MonadError[ErrorOr, String]

  val success = monadError.pure(42)
  println(success)
  // success: ErrorOr[Int] = Right(42)

  val failure = monadError.raiseError("Badness")
  println(failure)
  // failure: ErrorOr[Nothing] = Left("Badness")
```

The above code compiles and gives expected result.
Then I tried to do the same for `Try`

```scala
  import cats.MonadError
  import cats.instances.try_._
  type TryOr[A] = Try[A]
  val monadError = MonadError[TryOr, String]

  val success = monadError.pure(42)
  println(success)

  val failure = monadError.raiseError("Badness")
  println(failure)
```

this code doesn't compile. it says `no implicit found for parameter F:MonadError[TryOr, String]`
I went to the definition of MonadError and found following.

```scala
object MonadError {
  def apply[F[_], E](implicit F: MonadError[F, E]): MonadError[F, E] = F
}
```

But didn't understand why it worked for `Either` but not working for `Try`. Why we need additional implicit even after `import cats.instances.try_._`

Can you help understand what is happening in the background ?

Comment: A `Try` can't hold a `String` in the error channel, so no idea why you think it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Try` you should use only `Throwable` as an error type. This is a limitation of the `Try` design. `MonadError[Throwable, A]`. You can check `Try` instances `cats.instances.TryInstances`. There is only `MonadThrow` instance.

```
  type TryOr[A] = Try[A]
  val monadError = MonadThrow[TryOr]

  val success = monadError.pure(42)
  println(success)

  val failure = monadError.raiseError(new Exception("Badness"))
  println(failure)
```